# Location manager, not accurate even after setting kCLLocationAccuracyBest

Tags: mapkit, cllocationmanager

Hi there
I am using location manager and mapkit, i am able to get the curernt location, but its not accurate enough - This is my problem

1. My current location on the map is for example 3.0856333888778926, 101.67204022407532, but location manager's location only returns +3.08370327, +101.67506444; which is short of a few decimal numbers
2. This is resulting in the wrong location (about 1 KM away) when i try to show directions

I have already set location to be kCLLocationAccuracyBest -

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you try it? Inside, the accuracy of GPS is inherently limited (usually not to 1km, though. But within big cities, reflections from buildings are possible). Ahh, and another thing: is the measurement done inside the simulator? I'm not sure how the location is determined within it. But in my tests, I'm also usually quite off my actual position.

Comment: i try it on the actual device, am aware that it does'nt work on a simulator. the position is always off by 800meters to 1KM, i have read somewhere, i need to let the gps to atleast triangulate the position a few times, gonna try that

Comment: What is the accuracy reported (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy)? Is your position within it? Or do you use the position reported from mapview?

Comment: i got to understand that the location is not accurate the first time and takes a few tries before the actual/close to actual location is obtained - so i had to let the location manager find the location a few times

Comment: There is a similar discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540095/how-to-wait-until-location-is-completely-found-core-location

Answer (score 0):

It may be related on how you have setup your locationmanager.

Could you please post it here for us to check? Maybe this could help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on wifi? This happens to me if I am on wifi. When I switch to edge/3g, everything turns to normal. Just try with standard map application if it also shows you wrong.

Comment: hi Koray, thanks for your interest, but i did it this way:
Get the timestamps when locations changed, compare them and grab the latest. 
This seem to have worked, and my app does'nt really need totally accurate position; a rough estimate is good enough so it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

the highest possible accuracy and combine it with additional sensor data.

```
kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
```

This level of accuracy is intended for use in navigation applications that require precise position information at all times and are intended to be used *only while the device is plugged in.*