# How to wait until location is completely found? (Core Location)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-location

I have a problem within my app.  I'm trying to find the user's location to the best preciseness in order to determine their zip-code.  Currently I have a button that, when pressed, starts a method named `locateMe`.

```
-(IBAction)locateMe; {
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Then I've implemented `didUpdateToLocation:`

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
       didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation; { 

       NSLog(@"Found location! %f,%f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude,newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
 }
```

I had previously done much more complicated stuff in `didUpdateToLocation` but as I tested some things I realized that the first location it found was not precise in the least.  So, I put the `NSLog` call in there and it gave me an output similar to below...

```
Found location! 39.594093,-98.614834
Found location! 39.601372,-98.592171
Found location! 39.601372,-98.592171
Found location! 39.611444,-98.538196
Found location! 39.611444,-98.538196
```

As you can see, it first gives me a value which is not correct, which was causing problems within my app because it wasn't giving the correct location.

So, here's my question.  Is there any way I can wait for the location manager to finish finding the most precise location?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I'm wanting something like this:

```
if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= locationManager.desiredAccuracy) {
}
```

But it never gets called!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Core Location often call didUpdateToLocation with location detected durning previous session. So you can just skip first location that it send to you. And if you're calculating user speed based on this data you should to be aware of that behavior. Pedestrians at 100mph is usual in that case. :)

If you're submitting comments or photos with geo coordinates - start receiving geo coordinates when user did enter to write a comment screen. while he will type a message - detected location become pretty accurate.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I'm thinking I should just start receiving the location as soon as the settings view opens (that's where I'm grabbing my location).

Comment: Agreed. If you will start detecting location too early - it will drain device battery. So I recommend detect location only when it really necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  How can I discard the first location that it gives?  Would I use a counter?

Comment: If you didn't perform calculations based on location events - you just use latest location. Else you should store all received locations and then filter them. Anyway it's depends on your requirements. May be counter will be enough. We're finished speedometer with route recording and there was more complicated filtration and processing.

Answer (score 9):

I don't see how you expect this to work. There's no guarantee that you will ever obtain a location with a specific level of accuracy. You're assuming that you will eventually get a location that has the reported accuracy you desire and that won't necessarily happen. LocationManager will send you a sequence of location updates which are generally, but certainly not always, increasingly accurate. Unfortunately you can't demand that the device receive a signal strong enough for it to give you a position of arbitrary accuracy and there's no way the device can predict the future to say "this is the most accurate position I'm going to get".

You might try storing all the locations reported over some time interval or until the reported accuracy seems to stabilize and accept that after several seconds you're probably not going to get a significantly more accurate position. You could then use the last reported position, or the most accurate, or a weighted center point of all of them, or whatever you think makes sense.

Given that you say this is going to be used to perform a reverse geocoding to get a zipcode I have to wonder why this is a concern. Even the most granular position is probably going to hit the user's current zipcode and even the most accurate will never be exactly right in every case so you'll want to allow users to correct it anyway if this is visible to your users.

Comment: +1 I think this is the best answer. The location manager cannot possibly know when it received the most precise location.

Comment: This answer is correct, but pedantic. Of course it is impossible to detect when a location is as good as it is going to get (see: halting problem). Yet people nevertheless want to get good data with a tradeoff for time, and want best practices. What the OP wanted was abundantly clear - and it wasn't a lecture.

Evgen's answer, above, is the most productive.

Answer (score 2):

So you can really see what's happening, try NSLog'ging the horizontalAccuracy property of your newLocation object. You'll see that it's narrowing in on the location with each hit.

That means you can then TEST for the horizontal accuracy when your location manager gives you an update, and discard those that are too inaccurate for your use.

Comment: Ah, makes sense.  Never knew about that property. :)

Answer (score 1):

NSLog() the oldLocation property, I think it should (or shouldn't?) be nil. and you can hide the userLocation if something failed:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    mapView.showsUserLocation = NO;
}
```

//EDIT: the desiredAccuracy says that the `didUpdateToLocation` only gets called if you move that far away from the old position. If you set the desiredAccuracy to 100m it will only get called when the user moves 100m away from his old position.

Comment: When it's first started, the `oldLocation` is nil.  After one level down (in preciseness), it become non-nil.

Comment: yes thats what I mean. You can check if it's nil and don't execute the code you would normally do.

Comment: But even when it's non-nil it still isn't the level of preciseness that I need.

Answer (score 1):

Save off the launch (or wake) time of your application, and discard any results from location manager that are older than the time your app was launched.  CLLocation has a date stamp on it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm not sure you understand quite what I mean.  I don't start the location manager until a settings view is loaded.  I want to wait until the location is more precise, then grab the location data.  That was my question.

Comment: Right, but you can still store app launch time and not use any location dated before that - or in your case you could store the date the location manager was started, it would amount to the same thing.

Comment: This could get a little tricky if they start the app and then exit it (that is, it enters the background). At least this is my use case with the Maps application (start, pause, open, pause). Considering that I'm in my car, the resulting location can be quite far away. But as a sort of all-else-has-failed solution, it's not a bad one.

Comment: You can use the willResumeFromBackground notification to reset that launch datestamp.  Accept no date older than your resume, and basically kick the location manager once after that date reset is done - you are going to get at least one fresh location update if you stop and restart the location manager.